# GAT-related lifetime conflicts with mutex temporary lifetime

Tags: rust, generic-associated-types

I'm experimenting with GATs to enhance the API to an in-memory data store. The data is organized in values, where each value contains, among other things, a lookup key. You can think of it like a row in a database table, where the whole row is a "value", but it also contains a primary-key column or columns.

The idea is to describe this by a trait, so you can look for a particular value by providing the key. The key must be able to refer into the value, so that if the key-part of the value is `String`, you can look it up using just `&str`. This is where GATs enter the picture:

```
pub trait Value {
    type Key<'a>: PartialEq where Self: 'a;

    fn as_key<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::Key<'a>;
}
```

The `Key<'a>` GAT provides a lifetime that `as_key()` can use to return a value that refers to inner data. Note that `as_key()` can't just return a reference to the key because the returned key can be something that doesn't exist verbatim inside `Self`, such as a composite key. For example, these are all possible:

```
struct Data {
    s: String,
    n: u64,
    // ... more fields ...
}

// example 1: expose key as self.s as a &str key
impl Value for Data {
    type Key<'a> = &'a str;
    fn as_key(&self) -> &str { &self.s }
}

// example 2: expose key as a pair of (self.s.as_str(), self.n)
impl Value for Data {
    type Key<'a> = (&'a str, u64);
    fn as_key(&self) -> (&str, u64) { (&self.s, self.n) }
}
```

An example of generic code that makes use of this trait could look like this:

```
pub struct Table<T> {
    data: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T: Value> Table<T> {
    fn find<'a: 'k, 'k>(&'a self, k: T::Key<'k>) -> Option<usize> {
        self.data.iter().position(|v| v.as_key() == k)
    }
}
```

This works beautifully and you can play around with it [in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=03726034117e08d3c513a4660554bbe7). (A more realistic example would require `Ord` or `Hash` from `Value::Key` and build a more sophisticated storage, but this is enough to show the idea.)

Now, let's make a simple change and store the table data in a `Mutex`. The code looks almost the same, and since it only returns the *position*, the mutex manipulation should remain internal to the implementation:

```
struct Table<T> {
    data: Mutex<Vec<T>>,
}

impl<T: Value> Table<T> {
    pub fn find<'a: 'k, 'k>(&'a self, k: T::Key<'k>) -> Option<usize> {
        let data = self.data.lock().unwrap();
        data.iter().position(|v| v.as_key() == k)
    }
}
```

However, the above code doesn't compile - it complains that "data doesn't live long enough":

```
error[E0597]: `data` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:18:9
   |
16 |     pub fn find<'a: 'k, 'k>(&'a self, k: T::Key<'k>) -> Option<usize> {
   |                         -- lifetime `'k` defined here
17 |         let data = self.data.lock().unwrap();
18 |         data.iter().position(|v| v.as_key() == k)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^              ---------- argument requires that `data` is borrowed for `'k`
   |         |
   |         borrowed value does not live long enough
19 |     }
   |     - `data` dropped here while still borrowed
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c7e04df097dafa8ae8d17dabe5a62592)

I don't quite understand this error - why would `data` need to live for the lifetime of the key we're comparing it to? I tried:

- changing lifetimes so that lifetimes of `'k` and `'a` are fully decoupled
- extracting the comparison to a simple function that receives `&'a T` and `&T::Key<'b>`, and returns a `bool` after comparing them (and which compiles on its own)
- replacing `Iterator::position()` with an explicit `for` loop

But nothing helped, the error always remained in some form. Note that it's perfectly legal to place both `v.as_key()` and `k` in the same closure (e.g. [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3974dadc1dc62949c6992c79b129bf66)), it's only when you attempt to compare them that the error arises.

My intuitive understanding of the problem is that the `Eq` bound associated with `Value::Key<'a>` only applies to another `Key<'a>`.

Is it possible to rework the lifetimes or the `as_key()` interface to work around this issue? Is this a variant of the issue described [here](https://sabrinajewson.org/blog/the-better-alternative-to-lifetime-gats#where-real-gats-fall-short)?

---

**EDIT**: relaxing the `PartialEq` bound to HRTB `for<'b> PartialEq<Self::Key<'b>>` as suggested by kmdreko fixes the above examples, but breaks with generics. For example, this implementation of `Value` fails to compile:

```
struct NoKey<T>(T);

impl<T> Value for NoKey<T> {
    type Key<'a> = () where T: 'a;
    fn as_key(&self) -> () {
        ()
    }
}
```

with the error:

```
error[E0311]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:38:20
   |
38 |     type Key<'a> = () where T: 'a;
   |                    ^^ ...so that the type `NoKey<T>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=69b254503c27655e9c972ed43baa5ddc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My intuitive understanding of the problem is that the `Eq` bound associated with `Value::Key<'a>` only applies to another `Key<'a>`.

This is correct. You can relax this constraint by using a higher-ranked trait bound to require `Key<'a>` to be comparable to all `Key<'b>`:

```
pub trait Value {
    type Key<'a>: for<'b> PartialEq<Self::Key<'b>> // <-----
    where
        Self: 'a;

    fn as_key<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::Key<'a>;
}
```

I don't think there's any other way, because most types are covariant with respect to their associated lifetime, but with `T::Key<'k>` I don't think you can constrain that `'k` can be shortened.

The issue with generics pointed out in the edited question can be worked around by requiring the generic to be `'static` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=722a725e150b42d745baf1be93936bbe)). Note that the `'static` bound only applies to the value as a whole, the key may still refer to parts of the value.

Comment: This indeed solves the issue described in the question. But unfortunately, it appears to make it impossible to use generic types to implement `Value` (which was previously possible). For example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=07c8b5e0c5b17c9237a549a7b2fcd1d6

Comment: @user4815162342 **This** is the problem mentioned in Sabrina's post you linked. The problem is that the WF requirements for `for<'b> PartialEq<Self::Key<'b>>` implies `for<'b> Self::Key<'b>`, which (incorrectly) implies `Self::Key<'b>: 'c` for _literally any_ lifetime `'c`, i.e. `Self::Key<'b>: 'static`. This is intended to be fixed (by only requiring to outlive lifetimes where the type is WF with) and as far as I understand a-mir-formality proves this is possible, but there is still no timeline for a fix. I don't know a way around with current GATs, sadly, and IIRC it does not exist.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I'm not sure about the implied `Self::Key<'b>: 'static` bound. If it were implied, I'd expect the example with non-static `Key` not to compile, and [it does](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a91224dd19286ad99e574d72ab43c51a). The issue only appears when I introduce generics in the `Value` impl.

Comment: @user4815162342 it seems I don't have a solution for that. My hope would've been that `Key<'a>: for<'b> PartialEq<Self::Key<'b>>` just flattens down to `(): PartialEq<()>` when `Key<'a>` is `()`, but it seems that an additional lifetime constraint is still implied even when the `for<'b>` is unused. I'm not so sure about it being `'static` either but I hope that Chayim is right that it will be fixed eventually. Is there an issue for it?

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks for your assistance. I've now edited the question to include the generics requirement (which I wasn't aware would be an issue initially), sorry for moving the goalpost. +1 from me, but I'll refrain from accepting in hope a proper solution. I'm not aware of a GH issue for this, so I'll write one, as this looks different than the effectively-static requirement mentioned by Chayim.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thinking of it again, I'm not sure I'm right. It needs investigation.

Comment: It turns out that the generic issue is easily solved by adding the bound `T: 'static` on the generic. This didn't occur to me initially because the `'static` bound on the **key** would ruin it completely. But on the other hand, a static bound on the whole **value** is perfectly acceptable, at least in my use case.